# I need to JOIN using a linking table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The three tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    ArtistKey   char(20)    NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    ArtistName  varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE AlbumInfo
(
    AlbumInfoKey    char(20)    NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    AlbumTitle      varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    AlbumDate       date        NULL,
    AlbumStudio     varchar(50) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE AlbumArtist
(
    AlbumInfoKey char(20)   NOT NULL,
    ArtistKey    char(20)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    AlbumInfoKey    ASC,
    ArtistKey       ASC
))
```

My objective is to list all of the artists and their albums.  I  can't seem to get anything to work.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    Artist.ArtistName,
    AlbumInfo.AlbumTitle
FROM Artist
JOIN AlbumArtist 
   ON Artist.ArtistKey = AlbumArtist.ArtistKey
JOIN AlbumInfo 
   On AlbumInfo.AlbumInfoKey = AlbumArtist.AlbumInfoKey
```

However this gives me back nothing not even an error.

Comment: did you insert values to the tables?? for me it seems there's no problem with the tables or the join statments

Comment: Yes all the tables have values I have no output.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ed7198a08d2ec4e31a1e399c5566a8c) your issue. Please provide sample data for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your query is fine. You might want to check your data.

Comment: There might be a problem with trailing spaces. Considere an "ANSI_PADDING" problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I had to re-do your whole task, and I have come up with more professional, and better way of managing database. You need to drop those tables, and re-do whole thing like show in code below :

```
 --First create Artist table 
CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    Artist_key int  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ArtistName  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    
);

--Then create Album table
CREATE TABLE AlbumInfo
(
    Album_key int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    AlbumTitle      varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    AlbumDate       date        NULL,
    AlbumStudio     varchar(50) NULL,
    Artist_key int FOREIGN KEY (Artist_key) REFERENCES Artist(Artist_key)
);




-- Must have Artist data before referencing in the album table
INSERT into Artist (ArtistName) values ('John')
INSERT into AlbumInfo (AlbumTitle,AlbumDate,AlbumStudio,Artist_key) values ('ABC3','2020-6-12','Def3',(select Artist_key from Artist where Artist_key = 1  ))


--test if data has been inserted
SELECT * FROM Artist
SELECT * FROM AlbumInfo

-- And finally this query will show the Artist with their relevant Albums
SELECT ArtistName,af.AlbumTitle,AlbumStudio from Artist a join AlbumInfo af on af.Artist_key = a.Artist_key
```

And the result is :

[image]